# Neo4j Procedure with static variables in a cluster

Tags: neo4j, virtual-machine, neo4j-apoc

Let's say I have a Neo4j Database with a custom Procedure, I've written.
The procedure uses a static variable as some kind of some short term memory, like the apoc.search procedure does for example.
I now want to cluster my Neo4j which would mean I have multiple instances running on different VMs.
I now have the problem, that the clustered instances can't share the content of the static variable, right?
Is there some way to share this?

For better understanding lets say I re-implemented the apoc.create.vNode procedure by creating a node and saving it inside a `public static Node node;`, not in the Database. I've deployed the plugin into each instance of my cluster. When I now save a Node like that, it will just be known to one Neo4j instance, right?
When my instance dies, the node is forgotten.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. State held in procedures, even static state, is not shared across the cluster.

I think the only way to share it would be to save it into the graph itself.